# How do I get the MIN and MAX dates outside of a given date range with MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database of call records. I need to be able to query the records by date but still get the MIN and MAX of the `startdatetime` as the first and last time they called. The query below gives me the records between the given date range but the MIN and MAX values only return the MIN and MAX values between the date range not the actual first and last time the customer called. I'm using Laravel and below is my query to retrieve records.

```
$query = DB::table('callrecord')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('SUM(duration_seconds) as total_duration'),
        DB::raw('MIN(startdatetime) as first_called'),
        DB::raw('MAX(startdatetime) as last_called'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total_calls'),
        'phone'
    )

if ($startDate && $endDate) {
    $query->whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT(startdatetime, \'%Y-%m-%d\') >= ?', [$startDate])
        ->whereRaw('DATE_FORMAT(startdatetime, \'%Y-%m-%d\') <= ?', [$endDate]);
}

$callers = $query->groupBy('phone')
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $order)
    ->paginate($request->input('perPage', 15));
```

Below is the database structure and expected result. How can I get the actual first and last date a customer called outside of the date range?

```
// Database 
id  startdatetime   phone       duration_seconds
1   2020-01-03      0987654321  100
2   2020-02-03      0987654321  200
3   2020-03-03      0123456789  100
4   2020-04-03      0987654321  45
5   2020-05-03      0987654321  145


// Expected output for querying between dates 2020-02-03 - 2020-04-03
phone       total_duration  first_called    last_called     total_calls
0987654321  245             2020-01-03      2020-05-03      2
```

Comment: I think you'll need to do a subquery to get the min/max dates that are not within the constraints of your where clause.

Comment: Your query says the date should be between '2020-02-03' and '2020-04-03', this makes sue the MIN() and MAX() are also between those two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a temporary table to solve the issue. Here is the SQL for you.
You can convert my sql into the larvel syntax.

```
DROP Temporary table IF exists T_Test;
create Temporary table T_Test(firstcalled date, lastcalled DATE, phone integer);
INSERT INTO T_Test
select MIN(startdatetime), MAX(startdatetime), phone from Test
group by phone

SELECT * FROM T_Test;

SELECT SUM(duration_seconds) as total_duration, firstcalled, lastcalled, COUNT(id) as    total_calls FROM Test
LEFT JOIN T_Test ON T_Test.phone = Test.phone
WHERE Test.startdatetime BETWEEN '2020-02-03' AND '2020-04-03'
GROUP BY Test.phone
```